# Is it possible to update the flags of an existing memory mapping?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, shared-memory, mmap

I am writing a small program in x64 assembly that will spawn children, all sharing their memory mappings so they can modify each other's code. For this, since the argument `CLONE_VM` of `sys_clone` seems to place the program into undefined behaviour, I plan to use `mmap`'s `MAP_SHARED` argument.

However, I would also need the children to modify the code of the father. One option is to also allocate a `MAP_SHARED` mapping and give it to the father, but I'd like to avoid this if possible (only for elegance reasons).

Since the base mapping (the `0x400000` one on 64-bits Linux) of the program will not have the `MAP_SHARED` flag by default, is it possible to update it using a syscall to set this flag? `munmap` then `mmap` will not do and cause a SIGSEGV, and `mprotect` can only change the RWX permissions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, if only for security reasons.  Note that a `MAP_SHARED` mapping also affects the underlying file, so doing that to your text segment is out of question.  What you could do is copy the text segment into temporary storage, replace it with a new mapping and then write it back.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. I guess I'll go with giving a fresh mapping to the father, it shouldn't look too bad.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change whether an existing mapping is private or shared, but you can map a new shared mapping over an existing private mapping. You can even do so in C, like this:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *stream = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "rb");
    if(!stream) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    char *text_start, *text_end;
    do {
        if(fscanf(stream, " %p-%p%*[^\n]", &text_start, &text_end) != 2) {
            perror("scanf");
            return 1;
        }
    } while(!(text_start <= main && main < text_end));
    if(fclose(stream)) {
        perror("fclose");
        return 1;
    }
    size_t text_len = text_end - text_start;
    char *mem = mmap(NULL, text_len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if(mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    memcpy(mem, text_start, text_len);
    __builtin___clear_cache(mem, mem + text_len);
    if(mremap(mem, text_len, text_len, MREMAP_MAYMOVE|MREMAP_FIXED, text_start) == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mremap");
        return 1;
    }
    /* you can check /proc/PID/maps now to see the new mapping */
    getchar();
}
```

As a bonus, this program supports ASLR and doesn't require that the text section start at `0x400000`.

Comment: I see, that's interesting, I would have thought that mmap would fail if used on an existing mapping. I will try this when I'm back home. Thank you

Comment: It's not the `mmap` that is used on the existing mapping, it's the `mremap`. The `mmap` in this example may fail since it uses `PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC` so you might have to do that in two steps.